# Rational Software Architect operation arguments setting on sequence diagram

Tags: sequence-diagram, rational-rsa

I want to set different values to the same parameters of two different calls of the same operation on one diagram. I use "Argument" property of message.

Problem is that "in" and "out" parameters are listed in both "in" and "out" message signatures.

How can I make "in" parameters were listed only in "in" message signature and "out" parameters were only listed in "out" message signature?

Also some times I need to set only part of input or output parameters. But on the diagram all parameters are always listed.

How can I show on the diagram only some of the input or output parameters?

**For example**, we have two optional input parameters par1 and par2 in some operation. I want to show on the diagram call of this operations with only one input parameter.

How can I do it?

Thank you!